# Complex class - cross class implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

#### System Details

- FluentValidation version: FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0
- Web Framework version :ASP.NET Core 2.1

#### Issue Description

```
public class Address 
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Address).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Address cannot be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.City).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The City cannot be empty.");
    }
}
public class PersonBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address PermanentAddress { get; set; }
}
public class PersonGroupA : PersonBase
{
    public int TotalSaleCount { get; set; }
}
public class PersonGroupB : PersonBase
{
    public int TodaySaleCount { get; set; }
}
public class PersonBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonBase>
{
    public PersonBaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The First Name cannot be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Last Name cannot be empty.");
        RuleFor(x => x.PermanentAddress).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
    }
}

public class PersonGroupAValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonGroupA>
{
    public PersonGroupAValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.TotalSaleCount).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Total Sale Count cannot be empty.");
    }
}

public class PersonGroupBValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonGroupB>
{
    public PersonGroupBValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.TodaySaleCount).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Today Sale Count cannot be empty.");
    }
}
```

how to use base validator in child validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working when add likebelow

```
public class PersonGroupAValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonGroupA> {
  public PersonGroupAValidator() {
```

> ```
>     Include(new PersonBaseValidator());
> ```

```
    RuleFor(x => x.TotalSaleCount).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The Total Sale Count cannot be empty.");
  }
}
```